# php error Call to an undefined static method with PHPStan

Tags: php, laravel, phpstan

I have `phpstan` in my proyect to analyze all my code. I´m working with `laravel` and `php 8.2.`

My problem it´s that when i execute `phpStan` return any errors and i have one in my function that i´m calling a `scope function`. this call it´s:

`$empresas_informe_gts = Empresa::filtrarConLiquidacionesOrdenadosPorNombre($argsScope);`

and in `Empresa` i have this function defined:

```
public function scopeFiltrarConLiquidacionesOrdenadosPorNombre($query, $args)
```

But the analysis, return

```
Call to an undefined static method
         App\Models\Empresa::filtrarConLiquidacionesOrdenadosPorNombre().
```

I try to add in function:

```
/**
     * @param Query<String> $query
     * @return Object<Object>
     */
```

but i have same error. This function scope, have a `return $query` with any `joins` and method `get()`.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PhpDoc notation is not `@param` but `@method`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

/** @method static Builder filtrarConLiquidacionesOrdenadosPorNombre (array $args)
```

One of the points of `PHPStan` is to check type matching, so the more you typehint the more it can help.

```
public function scopeFiltrarConLiquidacionesOrdenadosPorNombre(Builder $query, array $args): Builder
```

A smaller point, as the query builder `Builder`, is an object you do  not have to return it in scopes. As objects is always passed by reference.

Comment: thanks for your response. but return same problem

Comment: i had wrote FiltrarConLiquidacionesOrdenadosPorNombre instead of filtrarConLiquidacionesOrdenadosPorNombre try with that